# How to stop request to socket without close or disconnect connection using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

I have an application in which all the online drivers are display. Now I have a list of cab request which is not yet accepted by any drivers which are online. Here there is also functionality to resend the pending request. That request is sent to all the driver one by one. Now I want the functionality like when I have resent request to all driver @ that time I want to cancel to jump that request from 1 to other driver. I have used socket.io. Now I want that functionality without closing socket connection. How can I do that?

This is my code:-

```
CabRequest.prototype.makeRequest = function (again) {
    //alert(again);
var self = this;
        if (++this.requestStack > size(taxis)) {
this.failure();
        self.myIntervalClear(this.makeRequestInterval);
        return;
        }

var lat1 = self.position.lat();
        var lon1 = self.position.lng();
        if (!again){
self.pending = $.map(taxis, function(value, index) {
return [value]; });
        for (var i = 0; i < self.pending.length; i++) {
console.log(haversine(lat1, lon1, self.pending[i].loc.position.lat(), self.pending[i].loc.position.lng()));
        self.pending[i].distance = haversine(lat1, lon1, self.pending[i].loc.position.lat(), self.pending[i].loc.position.lng());
        }
self.pending.sort(function(a, b) {
return parseFloat(a.distance) - parseFloat(b.distance);
        });
        }

if (!lat1 || !lon1 || !self.phonenumber || !self.vehicle || !self.fullname) return;
        // console.log(self.pending);
        if (self.pending.length == 0) {
console.log("NO DRIVERS");
        $("#alert").text("No Drivers");
        console.log(self);
        }
else {
self.currentDriverSending = 1;
        }
this.sendNextRequest();
};

//below code is use to send next request

CabRequest.prototype.sendNextRequest = function () {
//    alert(len);
    if (this.pending.length > 0 ) {
        var taxi = this.pending.shift();
            if (taxi == null) {
                console.log("NO TAXI FOUND");
                return;
            }
        nextDriver(this.uniqueId, taxis[taxi.id].fullname);
        AddDispatchLog(this.uniqueId, this.phonenumber, taxis[taxi.id].fullname, 'Dispatch');
        socket.emit(7,
        {
        id: taxi.id,
                lat: this.position.lat(),
                lon: this.position.lng(),
                fullname: this.fullname,
                dest: this.destination.lat().toString() + "," + this.destination.lng().toString(),
                vehicle: this.vehicle,
                date: this.date,
                additional: (this.info + '_' + price),
                minutesBefore: "5",
                phonenumber: this.phonenumber,
                uniqueId: this.uniqueId
        });
        currentDriver = taxi.id;
    }
    else {`enter code here`
    //myIntervalClear(makeRequestInterval);
    this.makeRequest(false);
    }
};
```

Now I want to stop request when user click on cancel button from frontend. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is not very detailed, nor is it clear what you are asking. To help others help you, please add some code. Write down what you've tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: SocketIO has functionality of 'rooms,' so if you want to sent a message to many people at once each one should join a room. If you want to send individual messages, then you can send them in that manner as well. If you are sending messages individually in a loop, then you can have a functionality in there to break the loop, record where you left off, and  on some condition and send a message to another driver, then go back and continue the loop where you left off.